# openui5/sapui5 preserves my Html, but doesn't bring it back

Tags: html, sapui5

I have a view which just has Html in it:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="myproduct.controller.report.Design"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    displayBlock="true">

    <core:HTML content='&lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/design.css" /&gt;' />
    <core:HTML id="content" />
</mvc:View>
```

I grab hold of the "content" so that I can do JQuery stuff:

```
  var $content = $controller.byId("content");
    $content.setContent("<div></div>");

    var p$Html = $.get(this.$api + "/getreport");

    var afterrendering = function(){
        var $content = $controller.byId("content");
        var $elem = $($content.getDomRef());
        //Pop the preserved content back into the view
        $elem.appendTo($controller.getView().getDomRef());

        p$Html.then(function(){
            $(p$Html.responseText).appendTo($elem);

            var $grid = $elem.find('.report-grid');
            $controller.attachPopupMenu($grid);
        });
    }
    $content.attachAfterRendering(afterrendering);
```

Now this is all very clever and so on, but I have had to put a hack in $elem.appendTo($controller.getView().getDomRef());

Generally when I raise a popup, the View should rerender, and it does, but inside openui5, it detects PreserveContent and pops the original rendering into a hidden area. When my event handler runs, it gets a reference to the hidden event.

I'm expecting that Preserved Content should be stored prior to rendering, and automatically restored before the afterRendering event.

Does anybody know why my Html sticks in the ForceHidden area?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the reason you are using jquery dom manipulation at all?

My first thought was to call `$content.setContent(p$Html.responseText)` in the `p$html.then()` handler and remove the afterrendering stuff.

If the HTML control does not support the html you want to display, i would instead insert a `html:div` directly into the view and use that:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="myproduct.controller.report.Design"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    displayBlock="true">

    <html:link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/design.css"/>
    <html:div id="content"/>
</mvc:View>
```

```
Controller.extend("myproduct.controller.report.Design",{
  onAfterRendering:function(){
    //The <html:div> is available in afterRendering
    var $div = $("#"+this.createId("content"));
    var p$Html = $.get(this.$api + "/getreport");
    p$Html.done(function(data){
      $div.html(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Currently I'm only using jQuery to attach the download, but I may do more in the future. It never occured to be that the html namespace was catered for within XmlView - it's pretty sweet when configured as default namespace! This solution works perfectly.

Comment: To be fair though, the OpenUI5 Html control just doens't seem to work for me whatever I try. This this method is better.